# Disable click event on Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have two item in my layout, a `Listview` and a `TextView`.

OnClickListener is set as,

```
holder.expand=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand_list);
holder.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
```

It works only when I click on `TextView` inside relativelayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/expand_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/info_workout"
                android:clickable="true">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/workouts_group"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/expand_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="15sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/workouts_group"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Click to Expand"
                    android:textColor="#ffa2a2a2"
                    android:textSize="10sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

**Listview row.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bullet"
        android:layout_width="10sp"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/bullet"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/workout_name"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bullet"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bullet"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:text="Pushups"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/workout_time"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ff9c9c9c"
        android:text="01:00"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain

Comment: This shouldn't be downvoted as I have also experienced such kind of problems and referred to SO for solutions.

Comment: please post adapter class and xml of row in listview

Comment: Are you sure the RelativeLayout's children are not consuming the click? I'm pretty sure the ListView is clickable. Would also explain why it works when the TextView is clicked, since it doesn't consume.

Comment: I had added, `android:clickable="false"` to listview. Still not working.

Comment: Added xml of row. Adapter class is too large to print here. But since onclick is getting called on clicking on Textview, there shouldn't be any problem with adapter.

Comment: what you want exactly? click on part of row (like ImageView or TextView ) or click on row ? what you have tried for that?

Comment: @hXT1022 `android:clickable="false"` does not disable clicks on the ListView (I know, right). Try setting `holder.expand.findViewById(R.id.workouts_group).setEnabled(false);` If the layout is clickable with the listview disabled, then it's confirmed that you'll need to change you design if you want the whole layout to be  clickable.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I want whole row to be clickable, not just the textview

Comment: @Kevin I added that code above. `expand.onClickListener`. not working

Comment: why you don't use `setOnItemClickListener` ? example : `listview.setOnItemClickListener(....)`

Comment: I added setOnItemClickListener for listview. Funny that it is not getting called

Answer (score 0):

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

// add the above line in parent layout..

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting TextView height as match_parent and added `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`